# A little confused about making a mobile friendly navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

So earlier this week I decided to give myself a project that I would be proud to put on my portfolio. I decided to make a photography website for a dummy company that I created. I am using Flexbox and for the most part, it is mobile responsive. However the one thing I can't figure out is how to make a responsive menu that collapses WITHOUT using Bootstrap. I realize that Bootstrap is very useful but I want to be able to create these things without the use of a framework. I have my hamburger icon with the class of hamburger and everything already in place. As well as some media queries. Can anyone help guide me through the process? Here is the site:
https://jorgeg1105.github.io/JG-Photography/

```js
//When the page loads, Fade in all divs with class hidden.
//Then Remove hidden class.
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.hidden').fadeIn(2000).removeClass('hidden');
});

//Fade In all h3 with class hidden.
//Remove hidden class.
$('h3.hidden').fadeIn(3000).removeClass('hidden');

//Image Filter
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#mainnav ul li a").click(function (){
  var category = $(this).attr("class");

  if (category == "all" ){
   $("#imgcontainer img").addClass("hidden");
   setTimeout(function (){
    $("#imgcontainer img").removeClass("hidden");
   });
  }
  else {
   $("#imgcontainer img").addClass("hidden");
   setTimeout(function(){
    $("."+category).removeClass("hidden");
   });
  }
 });
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
   display: flex;
   height: 100vh;
   overflow: hidden;
   font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}

#container {
 flex: 1 0 0;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

/*------------------------Classes to be added to the current active link on a page----------*/
.active {
 color: #766E6B;
}


/*-------------------------Top Navigation items---------------*/

/*--------------Side Navigation Styles--------------------*/
#sidenav {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 width: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 border-right: 6px solid #766E6B;
   overflow-y: auto;
}

#sidenav ul {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
   justify-content: center;
}

#sidenav ul li:first-child {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
#sidenav ul li:last-child {
  margin-top: auto;
  }

#sidenav a {
 padding: 20px;
 display: block;
}

#sidenav a:visited {
 color: white;
}

#sidenav a:hover {
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
}



/*-------------Header Styles-------------------------------*/
header {
 padding: 40px 30px;
 background-color: #F7F6F2;
}

header h1, h3 {
 font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
}

header h1 {
 font-size: 90px;
}

header h3 {
 font-size: 40px;
}

header a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 padding: 0 0 12px 0;
 line-height: 1.5em;
}

header a:hover {
 transition: color 1s;
 color: #766E6B;
}


.smalltxt {
 font-size: 12px;
}

.topnavitems {
 padding: 20px;
 position: relative;
}

/*------------------Main Navigation-----------------------*/

#mainnav {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: black;
}


#mainnav li {
 margin-right: 5px;

}

#mainnav a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 padding: 10px;
}

#mainnav a:hover {
 font-size: 20px;
 color: grey;
}

/*--------------------ImgContainer Area------------------------*/

#imgcontainer {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 padding: 30px 20px;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: #F7F6F2;
}

#imgcontainer img {
 flex: 1;
 width: 40vh;
 padding: 10px;
}

#imgcontainer img:hover {
 border: 2px solid black;
}
/*-----------------------Footer Styles---------------------*/

footer {
 background-color: #F7F6F2;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 border-top: 1px solid grey;

}

footer ul {
 justify-content: center;
}

footer li {
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.developer {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

/*-------------------Js Fade In class-------------------*/
.hidden {
 display: none;
}

/*-------------------Flexbox-----------------------*/
.col {
 flex: 1;
}

.row {
 display: flex;
}

/*----------------------Mobile Navigation------------------------*/

.mobilenav {
 background-color: black;
 justify-content: center;
 display: none;
}

.mobilenav ul {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 margin: 0;
}

.mobilenav li {
 margin-right: 10px;

}

.mobilenav a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding: 20px;
}

.mobilenav a:hover {
 background-color: grey;
}

/*-----------------Mobile Footer------------------------------*/
.mobilefooter {
 display: none;
}

.mobilefooter a {
 color: black;
}

/*-----------Media Queries----------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
 #sidenav {
  display: none;
 }

 nav.mobilenav.row {

  display: none;
 }

 .mobilefooter {
  display: flex;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 930px){
 #imgcontainer img {
  width: 80vh;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 740px){
 header a {
  display: none;
 }

 .mobilenav {
  display: flex;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 592px){
 header h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
 }

 header h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
 }

 #imgcontainer img {
  width: 95%;
 }

 .mobilenav {
  flex-direction: column;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>| J&amp;D |</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <!--Custom CSS-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/styles.css">
 <!--Google Fonts-->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400i|Tangerine:700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <nav id="sidenav" class="row">
  <ul class>
   <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
  <div id="container">
   <nav class="mobilenav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Questions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Rates</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="hamburger"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <header>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
     <ul>
      <li>
       <div class="topnavitems hidden">
        <a href="index.html">
         <strong class="active">Gallery</strong>
         <br>
         <span class="smalltxt">Our Work</span>
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="topnavitems hidden">
        <a href="#">
         <strong>About</strong>
         <br>
         <span class="smalltxt">D&amp;J Photography</span>
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="topnavitems hidden">
        <a href="#">
         <strong>Questions</strong>
         <br>
         <span class="smalltxt">Facts</span>
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
     <h1>D&amp;J Photography</h1>
     <h3 class="hidden"><em>"Explore. Create. Inspire."</em></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
     <ul>
      <li>
       <div class="topnavitems hidden">
        <a href="#">
         <strong>Rates</strong>
         <br>
         <span class="smalltxt">Your Investment</span>
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="topnavitems hidden">
        <a href="#">
         <strong>Contact</strong>
         <br>
         <span class="smalltxt">Get In Touch</span>
        </a>
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
    <nav id="mainnav">
   <ul class="row">
    <li><a href="#" class="all">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="food">Food</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="people">People</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="landmark">Landmarks</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nature">Nature</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="sneakers">Sneakers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="hamburger"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="imgcontainer">
   <a href="Images/Food/FriedChicken.jpg"><img src="Images/Food/FriedChicken.jpg" class="food"></a>
   <a href="Images/Nature/IcyMountains.jpg"><img src="Images/Nature/IcyMountains.jpg" class="nature"></a>
   <a href="Images/Landmarks/EiffelTower.jpg"><img src="Images/Landmarks/EiffelTower.jpg" class="landmark"></a>
   <a href="Images/People/Girl.jpg"><img src="Images/People/GuyInTrees.jpg" class="people"></a>
   <a href="Images/Sneakers/GoldAndWhite.jpg"><img src="Images/Sneakers/GoldAndWhite.jpg" class="sneakers"></a>
   <a href="Images/Food/ExoticDish.jpg"><img src="Images/Food/ExoticDish.jpg" class="food"></a>
   <a href="Images/Nature/VastLandscape.jpg"><img src="Images/Nature/VastLandscape.jpg" class="nature"></a>
   <a href="Images/Landmarks/LondonBridge.jpg"><img src="Images/Landmarks/LondonBridge.jpg" class="landmark"></a>
   <a href="Images/People/GuyWithCap.jpg"><img src="Images/People/GuyWithCap.jpg" class="people"></a>
   <a href="Images/Sneakers/Nike.jpg"><img src="Images/Sneakers/Nike.jpg" class="sneakers"></a>
   <a href="Images/Food/ShrimpRice.jpg"><img src="Images/Food/ShrimpRice.jpg" class="food"></a>
   <a href="Images/Nature/VeryGreenForest.jpg"><img src="Images/Nature/VeryGreenForest.jpg" class="nature"></a>
   <a href="Images/Landmarks/RomanColosseum.jpg"><img src="Images/Landmarks/RomanColosseum.jpg" class="landmark"></a>
   <a href="Images/People/OlderMan.jpg"><img src="Images/People/OlderMan.jpg" class="people"></a>
   <a href="Images/Sneakers/Vans.jpg"><img src="Images/Sneakers/Vans.jpg" class="sneakers"></a>
   <a href="Images/Sneakers/Yeezy.jpg"><img src="Images/Sneakers/Yeezy.jpg" class="sneakers"></a>
   <a href="Images/Food/SteakTacos.jpg"><img src="Images/Food/SteakTacos.jpg" class="food"></a>
   <a href="Images/Nature/MistyForest.jpg"><img src="Images/Nature/MistyForest.jpg" class="nature"></a>
   <a href="Images/Landmarks/GermanyCastle.jpg"><img src="Images/Landmarks/GermanyCastle.jpg" class="landmark"></a>
   <a href="Images/People/LittleGirl.jpg"><img src="Images/People/LittleGirl.jpg" class="people"></a>
  </div>
  <footer>
   <ul class="row">
    <li><p class="smalltxt">J&amp;G Photography all rights reserved &copy; 2017</p></li>
    <li><p class="smalltxt">Designed and Developed by <strong><a href="http://jorgegoris.com/" class="developer">Jorge Goris</a></strong></p></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="mobilefooter row">
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
  </footer>
 </div>
 <!--jQuery-->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <!--Font Awesome-->
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d579f311e9.js"></script>
   <!--Custom Js-->
   <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your goal is to build a good site in a timely manner use the right tools. If your goal is to learn a lot, enjoy yourself.

Comment: yup! Thats why I'm trying to get this done without Bootstrap. On Bootstrap this is super easy but I want to be able to create this myself. I want to see what goes into making it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is helpful:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 "use strict";
 var myNav = {
  init: function() {
   this.cacheDOM();
   this.browserWidth();
   this.bindEvents();
  },
  cacheDOM: function() {
   this.navBars = $(".navBars");
   this.xBxHack = $("#xBxHack");
   this.navMenu = $("#menu");
  },
  browserWidth: function() {
   $(window).resize(this.bindEvents.bind(this));
  },
  bindEvents: function() {
   var width = window.innerWidth;

   if (width < 600) {
    this.navBars.click(this.animate.bind(this));
    this.navMenu.hide();
    this.xBxHack[0].checked = false;
   } else {
    this.resetNav();
   }
  },
  animate: function(e) {
   var checkbox = this.xBxHack[0];
   !checkbox.checked ?
    this.navMenu.slideDown() :
    this.navMenu.slideUp();

  },
  resetNav: function() {
   this.navMenu.show();
  }
 };
 myNav.init();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #3e3e54;
}

.mainNav {
  background: #efefef;
  color: #1a1b18;
  max-height: 70px;
  position: relative;
}
.mainNav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.mainNav .logo {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 1.55em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  /*POSITION*/
  position: relative;
}
.mainNav .logo:hover:before {
  background: #292938;
}
.mainNav .logo:before {
  content: "";
  background: #3C91E6;
  z-index: -1;
  /*POSITION*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.mainNav .logo a {
  color: #efefef;
}
.mainNav .menu {
  background: #efefef;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  /*POSITION*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.mainNav .menu a {
  color: #292938;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
}
.mainNav .menu a:hover {
  background: #292938;
  color: #efefef;
}
.mainNav .navBars {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*USER SELECTION*/
  -moz-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
       user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

#xBxHack {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -99999px;
}
#xBxHack:checked ~ nav .menu {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .mainNav {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .mainNav .navBars {
    display: none;
  }
  .mainNav .container {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  .mainNav .logo {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .mainNav .menu {
    display: block;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    float: right;
    /*POSITION*/
    position: static;
  }
  .mainNav .menu li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .mainNav .menu a {
    border: none;
    padding: 20px 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--PEN CODE-->
<input type="checkbox" id="xBxHack" />
<nav id="mainNav" class="mainNav">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="logo"><a href="#">my<strong>Nav</strong></a></div>
  <label class="navBars" for="xBxHack">
   <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </label>
  <ul id="menu" class="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Profolio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining the magic? because this is not making too much sense to me :/